# apt-get update not working (LOOK STACK-TRACE)

Tags: apt, updates

After executing `sudo apt-get update` in a Azure VM I receive this output:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                              
Hit:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                        
Get:4 http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease [2835 B]                                                                
Get:5 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                                       
Get:6 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                                      
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                         
Err:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease         
Ign:9 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease                              
Hit:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
Get:11 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB] 
Hit:11 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release                                       
Get:13 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [724 kB]
Get:14 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [587 kB]                
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7CDE3A860A53F9FD
Err:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Fetched 1621 kB in 0s (2135 kB/s)                     
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7CDE3A860A53F9FD
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7CDE3A860A53F9FD
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I saw many similar issues here or googling, but none of them is actually working for me and I still receive the reported error.

Feel free to ask for more details, if you think it is duplicated, please report me the link

Comment: So, install gnupg? "Could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)"

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks for your reply; when I use `sudo apt-get install gnupg` I receive `gnupg is already the newest version (1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1).`, so I think is already installed

Comment: "Couldn't create tempfiles": are you on a read-only filesystem or is it full?

Comment: I think it is a normal File System, not read-only (sorry for my ignorance, but I can tell you that it is a normal VM Ubuntu 16.04 LTS provisioned by Azure, I don't think it is read only). For further details feel free to ask, please :)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I noticed that following some troubleshooting online i "disabled" /etc/apt/sources.list, so re-enabling it I received the new stack-trace that I edited in my question. While according to your previous question, with `ls -l /var/lib/apt/lists/` I noticed that each file has -rw-r--r-- privilege, so I should be able to write too

Comment: UPDATE according to [this](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/problem-with-apt-ubuntu-16-04.341306/) and using `chown root:root /tmp`
`chmod 1777 /tmp` changed something and now I have the re-edited (one more time) stack-trace

Comment: @karel now yes! Thanks very much, I followed instructions of the second reply (with score 386) and now the command worked! :D
Now, since it is a duplicate, I am supposed to delete this question?
P.S: **thank you very much everybody!**